# Find instances of a field where corresponding values in another, which should be 1-1, have more than one value

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a website sessions table with session id as the key. Each session should only have a single source - where the session came from. However, a small minority appear twice. Of those who appear twice, a smaller minority still have differing sources.

If I have a table of the form:

```
session_id | source
123456 | apples
abcdef | oranges
654321 | apples
abc123 | pears
def456 | oranges
123456 | pears
```

Each id should have only a single source. However, id 123456 has both apples and pears as a source. I would like to write a query that returns the ids like 123456, where they have more than one source next to them.

How could I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aggregate per session and count number of different sources:

```
select session_id, string_agg(distinct source, ',') as sources
from mytable
group by session_id
having count(distinct source) > 1
order by session_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can take the distinct session_id and source and get the count(*) bigger than 1

```
select session_id
from (select distinct session_id, source from tbl) a
group by session_id 
having count(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 1):

`having` clause is good but dramatically slow just because it needs to scan the whole table.

Having appropriate indexes, try to start somewhere like

```
select *
from
    your_table as t1 join your_table as t2 on (t1.session_id = t2.session_id and t1.source <> t2.source);
```

Thanks to @ThorstenKettner for reminding me about `exists`, this could be even more efficient:

```
select * from your_table as t1
wherte
    exists (
        select 1 from your_table as t2
        where t1.session_id = t2.session_id and t1.source <> t2.source)
```

Comment: For this query you'd want an index on `(session_id, source)`. The same index would be used for the aggregation. I suppose that the aggregation would be faster than your query, but that depends on how good Postgre's optimizer is. An alternative to the aggregation and better approach than a join would be an `EXISTS` clause in my opinion.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Surely, `join` could be more efficient then `having` and `exists` could be more efficient then `join`. Hope that Q author will return to this topic when his DB becomes to several TB :)